# The infimum of a moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, supremum-and-infimum, moment-generating-functions

Studying probability theory using Grimmett and Stirzaker's book and their solution for this question was (predictably) sparse, so I'm hoping someone else can explain it:

For $X$ a random variable with moment generating function $M_{X}$, show that:

$P(X\geq x) \leq \inf_{t \geq 0} \left \{e^{-tx}M_{X}(t)
  \
\right \}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used Chernoff's bound. Which itself is derived from Markov's bound.

Markov's bound is (for non-negative random variable $X$)
$$\mathbb{P}(X>x)\le \frac {\mathbb{E}(X)}{x}$$
Then
$$\mathbb{P}(e^{tX}>e^{tx})\le \frac {\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})}{e^{tx}}= M_X(t)e^{-tx} $$
Since this is true for all $t > 0 $ (since when $t<0$ the inequality inside the probability gets reversed), you can choose $t$ such that the RHS is minimized.

Comment: ah okay so since e^tX is itself a random variable you can plug it into Markov's inequality, which rewritten in this instance is equal to the RHS. And if it's true for any t>0, certainly it's true for the infimum. Awesome.